# How to create a new project using both App Engine Standard (Java 8) and Gradle

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, java-8, google-cloud-intellij

I'm trying to create a new project and running into trouble combining the App Engine Standard project type with Gradle. I've tried creating a Gradle project and adding App Engine Standard to it, and I've tried creating an App Engine Standard project and adding Gradle to it. Neither have yielded a working result. I'm sure it is a matter of not knowing the correct sequence of actions to take and / or choices to make in the dialogs, but the documentation doesn't address this combination well. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle) doesn't describe how to start a new project through IDEA, it simply points at a GitHub repo as an example of a finished product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDEA Cloud Tools plugin supports new project generation but only for native IntelliJ projects and doesn't generate a build.gradle for you.

I wouldn't recommend it as a starting point for a gradle based project anyway due to its directory structure.

IMO using the starter project on Github from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle#creating_a_new_project) you mentioned is the best approach to start.  You can clone it, delete the .git directory and import that into IntelliJ and should have a decent starting point for your project.

Comment: Do you see that as a documentation bug, or an issue with the output of the plugin? Specifically, do you think that the online documentation that details both Maven-based and Gradle-based workflows to build and deploy should be augmented with another variant to cover Intellij native projects, or do you see the problem as one of the plugin not producing the file / directory structure you consider best practice?

Comment: It is also worth noting that the process suggested in your answer does not yield either a java-8 based project (the subject of the original question) nor a working `Google App Engine Standard Local Server` build configuration in IDEA (`Error: Artifact isn't specified`).

Comment: The default Gradle getting started experience should be Java 8 runtime based.  I've added an internal bug (b/70555407) to track this.

The java 7 sample has incompatible gradle and app-gradle-plugin versions which breaks project import. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/953

Finally you found an artifact bug we see occasionally in Gradle IntelliJ projects. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1625

We're looking at the sample to see if we can use it to help diagnose the root cause as we have had issues replicating.

Thank you

Comment: was being short to fit character limits. :)

We really appreciate the feedback and are sorry you've hit so many bugs along the way to start using the java 8 runtime.  We will be prioritizing these issues right away so you should see improvements soon.  

As a workaround you may want to try removing any existing app engine facets (make sure you have the latest cloud tools plugin for intellij), and using 'add framework support' (right click on your project tree), and selecting App Engine Standrad if you can.